# How to integrate stuff like $\dfrac{v'(t)}{\sqrt{v(t)^2+c^2}}$ with respect to $t$?

Tags: calculus, integration

An integral arising from geometry. $v(t)$ is just a smooth function. If I consider derivative of $v^2$, which is $2vv'$, then I am missing a $v$ in the numerator.

Edit: Consider $\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{v^2+c^2}} dv$. Then employ a complicated trigo substitution.

Comment: This has a direct antiderivative - what have you attempted?

Comment: What happens if you use the substitution $u=v(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute $v(t)=c\tan\theta$. That will yield $\int\sec\theta d\theta$, which is [a standard integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).